# DateTime with "fa-IR" culture is Gregorian on specific server

Tags: c#, .net, iis

I am converting the current DateTime to a string with persian cultureInfo with code below:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/mm/dd", new CultureInfo("fa-IR"))
```

So the result of this code is something like :"1400/03/24"

it works perfectly on my code and others and also working fine on many IIS servers that my web application is on them but on specific servers it is not and it displays only Gregorian Date. Is there any settings that should be on my code or that IIS server?

Comment: Are the different servers on the same OS version and patch level? Cultures change over time and some of your machines may not be up to date.

Comment: I use IIS so both of them are windows

Comment: Yes, but which version of Windows? And which service pack level? And which patches Windows updates have been applied?

Comment: You could also try storing the culture in an object and setting the calendar type manually. For example: `var culture = new CultureInfo("fa-IR");` and then `culture.DateTimeFormat.Calendar = new PersianCalendar();`

Comment: @DavidG Would you please expand your answer a little more and give me more complete example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are specific servers different from other servers? you can try to use the NET Globalization feature page to configure .NET Framework globalization settings in iis.

Change Culture and UICulture to fa-IR and set enableClientBasedCulture True.

More information about the use of .NET Globalization Settings you can refer to this link:  [.NET Globalization Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc771836(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).